# Bios 'no bootable device' after Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS installation

Tags: boot, server, bios

Good day, everyone.

I'm desperately asking for help on topic.

Running a PC on Intel Atom 64bit with BIOS, not UEFI.

After what seems a successful installation of Ubuntu Server and reboot with USB stick removed, I keep getting this 'no bootable device' message.
Drive is recognized in BIOS and is 1st in boot order.
Tried installing w and w/t LVM. Full disk usage - need only this OS..

So, somehow during Ubuntu Server installation GPT gets applied as default and cannot be avoided explicitly... Curse it..
I've tried formatting disk via ZAPping GPT with `gdisk /dev/sda` *etc.* and applying MBR table with `fdisk /dev/sda` *etc.*
As a result I've got an empty unallocated MBR disk shown as of DOS (or smth like that) type in `fdisk -l`.
This should be correct as my Live USB with Debian **IS** of the same DOS type and boots without any problems....
BUT...still succeeding Ubuntu Server reinstallation applies that damned GPT on the disk......

**UPD**:
Well I've played **again** a little with disk partitions and tables and Distros...
Ubuntu and Debian desktops create an MBR table on disk during installation, install GRUB and boot just fine...
Drive prepartitioning is pointless as Ubuntu Server distro ignores everything and makes own <strike>shit</strike> mess... Still, it creates 2 partitions with flags: dev1 'bios_grub' of 1MB length from 2048s and dev2 'Linux filesystem', so all seems fine from this perspective... 
*But* it doesn't boot...

So,I've tried to install GRUB from Debian Live CD to `/dev/sda` via `chroot`. Terminal says everything is done with no errors, generates `grub.cfg`, but still no boot...

---


Have triple checked BIOS and found no possible adjustments able to solve the problem... I suppose smth is very wrong with Us installer.. Will try to post on Ubuntu Forums, maybe will be lucky to get some official feedback...


---

To me it seems really sick and <strike>fu</strike> messed up that simple OS installation turns 2 weeks of your live in hell....

Comment: If you partition in advance and use gpt, you have to have a bios_grub partition for BIOS  boot or an ESP - efi system partition for UEFI boot. There are some advantages to gpt, but gpt is required for drives over 2TiB and really should only be used with UEFI. You only install grub to MBR of a drive like sda, never to partition like sda1. If gpt, you still install to gpt's protective MBR, but gpt does not have sectors just after MBR, so bios_grub is where it writes core.img. Listing of gpt partitions may show MBR with one gpt partition which is the protective MBR so old tools do not erase it.

Comment: @oldfred, thanks for your assistance, but the more I read, the more I get confused, especially by the GPT part :) I'd tried to install GRUB to `/dev/sda` on GPT disk after Us installation as you've said via these [instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/183056/267875), as only `chroot` helped, but still no luck..  And now I blame GPT auto partitioning during install. Tonight I've got an idea to fully install Debian and to examine HDD situation afterwards, because Debian boots just fine....

Comment: If doing an install with gpt partitioning you need bios_grub partition or ESP.  If command line you need to create partition with parted or gdisk. If drive is blank installer will create the correct partition. And gpt is required for large drives, but optional for smaller ones. But MBR is now 35 years old and has many kluges to keep it working. I consider it better to use gpt and have used it since 2011, but had to always add the bios_grub partition for my old BIOS system, and now an ESP for my new UEFI systems. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/

Comment: @oldfred, I've got a little update.. Just in case you might decide to provide further assistance.

Comment: Only installed server as test years ago. But if you get grub menu can you boot recovery mode? Or remove quiet splash from linux line in grub ( e for edit) and see if you get error messages. Do not know if this runs in newer gui server installer or not: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred, unfortunately, I haven't succeeded with making GRUB work yet.. US installer provides full installation log, but only way to share it would be video :) Ok, I'll try Boot-Repair as you say, thank you for your time and attention :)

Comment: @oldfred, here is my [Boot-info summary report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/m5d347yDBc/) hope it will clarify anything...

Comment: You have a standard BIOS boot install using gpt. And it does have the required bios_grub partition. You may need in UEFI/BIOS make sure settings are legacy/CSM/BIOS or whatever your system calls it and not UEFI boot mode as default. IF you hold shift key from UEFI/BIOS do you get grub menu? If so then you may need boot parameters for your system, but that can vary greatly.

Comment: @oldfred, you see, I definitely can't show up GRUB via Shift and I'm almost confident that there is no such tweak in BIOS that I have... I'd tried altering 'Drive mode' option to Legacy and back to Normal, but that had no result.. I could create an album and give you a link, if you please, maybe your skilled and fresh eye will catch smth relevant :)

Comment: Boot-Repair report showed normal. Not familiar with Atom other than knowing they are lightweight chips with some limits. What brand/model motherboard or system? Some early models were 32 bit UEFI but 64 bit chips. But you would not have been able to boot standard Ubuntu if 32 bit. Do not know if this is related? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1727356

Comment: @oldfred, unfortunately no. If I'm not mistaken, that bug report is about graphics issue and absence of login screen. Me, I'm getting the explicit message from BIOS (after it loads) at the boot stage 'no bootable device'. Before it tries to boot from Ethernet, which goes after HDD in boot order.... I'll check my motherboard. I'll make another attempt tomorrow with that Legacy HDD mode, then will try to convert GPT to MBR ([suggested at Superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1338588/863127)), and at last will dive into DUET solution. If you won't come up with another idea, of course. Many thanks :)

Comment: You can use this to convert to MBR without total reinstall. But probably have to reinstall grub as core.img needs to be in sectors after MBR, and with gpt core.img is in bios_grub partition. Converting to or from GPT
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html

Comment: @Denis.Z, any luck on boot issue? I'm also experiencing this very issue with an Intel Atom D510 (D510MO) that can boot without problems other linux systems from the hard drive. Thanks.

Comment: @danieldeveloper001, see my answer.

Comment: @Denis.Z, so the real issue is that the installer is converting the disks from `mbr` to `gpt` and no questions  are made on this regard, at least now we know. I'll give it a try when a new setup is required on this machine but, for now, I've moved to Fedora Server, since it gives me more control over the partitioning scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've done it!

Solution that worked for me is quite simple but has been not too obvious...
A key to success is converting from GPT to MBR.

1. Install Ubuntu Server to target Drive the conventional way with it's installer (it did fine with auto partitioning).
2. Boot from probably any other (Debian type?) Linux Live dist.
   You may check:

   - all drive(s) partitions with <kbd>sudo fdisk -l</kbd> or
   - target Drive prtns. with <kbd>sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd*</kbd> <sub>(arguments may be reversed, sorry, don't have an access to terminal to make sure)</sub> exactly if you know Drive name (`sda`, `sdb`, etc.).

   <sub>(for other info, see `fdisk` man/help/info - it's straight & simple)</sub>
   Your target Drive will have most likely a 'bios_grub' prtn. and GPT OS prtn. with label 'Linux'.
3. Prepare the **Partition** for converting from GPT to MBR via <kbd>sudo gdisk /dev/sd**</kbd> (in my case it was `sda2`) and separate char commands <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd> each followed by <kbd>enter</kbd>.
4. If table output is OK, then <kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd>. Convertion may take some time (mine took about 2h+) with no progress UI, but continuous drive led flashing and HDD crackle might help you. As a result you'll get a 'bios_grub' prtn. left <sub>(I've decided to let it be, being afraid after so many days of headache of possible problems after deleting 1st prt. and moving 2nd)</sub> and a new MBR prtn.

   - You may check your OS prtn. with `fdisk` and, if needed, turn on `is_bootable` flag or change label.
5. Finally, you may need to install/update GRUB. Comprehensive [Instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/183056/267875) here.

For me, with all these steps covered, Ubuntu Server installation finished with a successfull boot.